# @RabbitListener throw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exchange name required; binding queue xxx

Tags: rabbitmq

I try to use @RabbitListener to create and bind exchange and queue automatically, but it throw the exception.

```
2023-02-19 16:56:58.040 ERROR 23348 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'certificateApplyEventHandler' defined in file [E:\codes\trace-platform\supervise\core\target\classes\tp\adapter\event\handler\CertificateApplyEventHandler.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exchange name required; binding queue EnterpriseCertificateApplyEvent
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at tp.TracePlatformApplication.main(TracePlatformApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exchange name required; binding queue EnterpriseCertificateApplyEvent
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:136) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.declareExchangeAndBinding(RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:651) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.registerBeansForDeclaration(RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:620) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.resolveQueues(RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:582) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processListener(RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:430) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processMultiMethodListeners(RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:381) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:299) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1807) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

my code is

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.Exchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.QueueBinding;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitHandler;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import tp.application.SuperviseService;
import tp.core.event.DomainEventHandler;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

/**
 * @author jh
 * @date 2023/2/16 23:04
 */
@Component
@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
        exchange = @Exchange(name = "trace_exchange"),
        value = @Queue(value = "trace_queue")
))
public class CertificateApplyEventHandler implements DomainEventHandler<EnterpriseCertificateApplyEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CertificateApplyEventHandler.class);

    @Resource
    SuperviseService superviseService;

    @Override
    @RabbitHandler
    public void onApplicationEvent(EnterpriseCertificateApplyEvent event) {
        superviseService.onCertificateApply(event);
    }
}
```

When I debug into the rabbit register code, I found the Annotation @Queue and @Exchange didn't work.
the string of rabitListener bean is:

@org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener(ackMode=, admin=, autoStartup=, bindings=[@org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.QueueBinding(admins=[], arguments=[], declare=true, exchange=@org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.**Exchange(admins=[], arguments=[], autoDelete=false, declare=true, delayed=false, durable=true, ignoreDeclarationExceptions=false, internal=false, name=, type=direct, value=**), ignoreDeclarationExceptions=false, key=[], value=@org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.**Queue(admins=[], arguments=[], autoDelete=, declare=true, durable=, exclusive=, ignoreDeclarationExceptions=false, name=EnterpriseCertificateApplyEvent, value=EnterpriseCertificateApplyEvent))]**, concurrency=, containerFactory=, errorHandler=, exclusive=false, executor=, group=, id=, priority=, queues=[], queuesToDeclare=[], returnExceptions=)

Why the name and value I set gone?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is IDEA cache problem.

I run `mvn clean` and then rerun, it works.